# Retrieving table via relational table in Laravel models

Tags: many-to-many, laravel-4, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, pivot-table

I have a database called "recipe-book" that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_recipe-book |
+-----------------------+
| ingredients           |
| migrations            |
| recipe_categories     |
| recipe_ingredients    |
| recipes               |
| users                 |
+-----------------------+
```

I have set up models in Laravel for a users recipes so I can return them like this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
return $user->recipes;
```

This works perfectly, however, now I naturally want to list the ingredients for a given recipe right? I want to do something similar like this

```
$recipe = Recipe::findOrFail($id);
return $recipe->ingredients;
```

The problem for me now is how to understand how to achieve this. In my database I have a relational table called "recipe_ingredients" for each ingredient like so:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| recipe_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ingredient_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| quantity      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The idea is that I can then more easily retrieve all the recipes that contain a specific ingredient. What I want though when I run:

```
return $recipe->ingredients;
```

Is both the "quantity" column from the relational table, as well as the information about that specific recipe, i.e. the table "ingredients".

How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this as models:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Recipe');
    }

}

class Recipe extends Eloquent {

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Ingredient', 'recipe_ingredients')->withPivot('quantity');
    }

}

class Ingredient extends Eloquent {

    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe', 'recipe_ingredients')->withPivot('quantity');
    }

}
```

And now you can do

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $user = User::find(1);

    var_dump($user->email);

    foreach($user->recipes as $recipe)
    {
        var_dump($recipe->name);

        foreach($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient)
        {
            var_dump($ingredient->name);
            var_dump($ingredient->pivot->quantity);
        }

        foreach($ingredient->recipes as $recipe)
        {
            var_dump($recipe->name);
            var_dump($recipe->pivot->quantity);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the migration I used here:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateIngredientsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recipes', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
        });

        Schema::create('ingredients', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });

        Schema::create('recipe_ingredients', function($table)
        {
            $table->integer('recipe_id');
            $table->integer('ingredient_id');
            $table->string('quantity');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('recipes');
        Schema::dropIfExists('ingredients');
        Schema::dropIfExists('recipe_ingredients');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I get the logic, but how would the Ingredient model as well as the pivot models look like?

Comment: The echo line doesn't really work as intended too, but it is an easy fix. However, I can't really make it work. Any tips?

Comment: This is a general rule to build relations in Laravel and I can assure you it works. But this is not really a full and tested code, it's just to show you how things works and how you can use it. This echo for example, might not work inside quotes, just remove them and it will work fine. Making the whole thing work also depends on your database, because if you don't have data filled correctly it will surely looks like it's not working. Share some code and people here might be able to help you more.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer me, I just getting to know Laravel and how basic relationship works. I have set up the models just like your example and the problem I have is that the ingredient object only returns the relational table like so:{"recipe_id":1,"ingredient_id":1,"quantity":"2dl"}, but the actual ingredient is in the table "ingredients" where the name is etc. How to I get that table along with it?

Comment: Just reproduced the whole thing and tested here. Edited with the working code.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that you edited your answer totally, I makes more sense now. I will examine this more thoroughly to learn it all :)